# Moodle & Umbraco - MYSQL Exception

Tags: asp.net, mysql, umbraco

I installed Umbraco on my server, it has MySQL.Data.dll 5.1.2.2 in bin file.

I created a ASP.NET user controls that insert users to Moodle DB, ( Generated DataLayer using Subsonic).

I generated DataLayer in Subsonic solution that has MySQL.Data.dll 5.1.4.0.

Now Umbraco is working fine, but the control that has Inserting To MYSQL DB is generating the below error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'MySql.Data, Version=5.1.4.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=e9238d4446c6cba1' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

If I copy MySQL.Data.dll 5.1.4.0 to Umbraco bin folder, all Macros in Umbraco are not working and giving me  XSLT Parsing error..

How can I solve that problem?

What about redirecting assembly versions in `web.config`?? How can setup that?? And will it work?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling  MYSQL Connector to latest version and doing [Assembly Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to 6.2.3.0 solved the problem